# How to tell the difference between target and source table?

Tags: mysql, orm, sequelize.js, relational-database, associations

Recently, I was using sequelize.js and MySQL. And I am a bit confused about the "target table" and "source table" when using `hasMany` / `belongsTo` to build association between different models.

For example, if I want to build a one-to-many between `Users` table and `Posts` Table(i.e. One user can have many posts whereas one post can only be owned by one user). Who is the target table and who is the source table?

If I change the scenario to one-to-one / many-to-many, who is target and who is source?

Answer (score 0):

See **Source and target** section in [Associations](https://sequelize.org/v5/manual/associations.html)

> User model (the model that the function is being invoked on) is the source. Project model (the model being passed as an argument) is the target.

Comment: Thank you! For a long time, I thought the difference between source and target is due to the schema of tables (i.e. who has the foreign key in the table). If it's differentiated by the model, it all makes sense!